# Scala warning a type was inferred to be 'AnyVal'

Tags: scala, warnings, type-inference

I have this actor with the following recieve code:

```
override def receive: Receive = {

case RefreshAccessTokenRequest(accountId, Some(refreshToken), _, _) =>
  concurApi.refreshAccessToken(accountId, refreshToken) onComplete {
    case Success(refreshTokenResult) =>
      context.parent ! ConcurResultCallbackInformation(accountId, Right(refreshTokenResult))
      accountService.updateAccountOAuth2Credentials(accountId, refreshTokenResult.toOAuth2Credentials) recover {
        case ex => logger.error("Error updating account Id: " + accountId + " with new refresh token. message: " + ex.getMessage)
      }
      context.stop(self)
    case Failure(t) =>
      context.parent ! ConcurResultCallbackInformation(accountId, Left(t))
      context.stop(self)
  }

case Cancel => context.stop(self)

case x => logger.error(s"ConcurAccessTokenActor: Got an unknown message $x")

}
```

I am getting a warning on the bolded part which says:

Warning:(18, 42) a type was inferred to be `AnyVal`; this may indicate a programming error.
        case Success(refreshTokenResult) =>

this is the refreshAccessToken function:

```
def refreshAccessToken(accountId: String, refreshToken: String)(implicit context: ExecutionContext) : Future[ConcurRefreshTokenResult] = {
val body = s"client_id=${sandboxClientId}"

val futureRes = ws.url(sandboxRefreshTokenFullUrl).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(body)
futureRes.flatMap { res =>
  res.status match {
    case 200 =>
      val extract = Try {
        res.body.fromJson[ConcurRefreshTokenResult]
      }.recover { case ex =>
        throw ex
      }
      Promise.fromTry(extract).future
    case 400 =>
      Future.failed(new RuntimeException(s"refresh Access Token failed with status 400, and body: ${res.body}"))
    case x =>
      Future.failed(new RuntimeException(s"refresh Access Token failed with status $x, and body: ${res.body}"))
  }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is your line 18 ?

Comment: What are the return types of `.info` and `.stop`?

Comment: Line 18: case Success(refreshTokenResult) => . notice the arrow points on the '=>' arrow

Comment: .info (you meant .error) and .stop are all of UNIT type.
I think i found the reason though... the 'updateAccountOAuth2Credentials' function returns Future[Boolean] so the return type of the entire block is of AnyVal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it..

The warning came from this code part:

```
case Success(refreshTokenResult) =>
  context.parent ! ConcurResultCallbackInformation(accountId, Right(refreshTokenResult))
  accountService.updateAccountOAuth2Credentials(accountId, refreshTokenResult.toOAuth2Credentials) recover {
    case ex => logger.error("Error updating account Id: " + accountId + " with new refresh token. message: " + ex.getMessage)
  }
  context.stop(self)
```

the 'updateAccountOAuth2Credentials' function returns Future[Boolean] yet the recover part returns Unit so it interperts it to AnyVal

I think the only thing that is confusing is the location of the warning arrow since this function appears in the middle between 2 other functions, and has no effects on the return type of the entire case block